# Eclipse plugin to SonarQube 4.0 not finding provisioned project or creating new project

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I am running the SonarQube plugin with m2e integration inside Eclipse Keplar. I am trying to run with a SonarQube 4.0 standalone server, running from the command-line on a win7 64 box.

When installing and reloading Eclipse the sonar plugin detected m2e and turned on the Sonar "nature" for me, including a project tag. The install also configured the SonarQube Eclipse properties to point to the localhost:9000 server. I can log in to the running server with chrome, and the Eclipse properties has a "test connection" option which passes. I am using empty user and password.

Problem 1: When I try and run SonarQube->Analyze on my project it completes and populates my project with issues. Great, except that this information is not pushed to the server and the start of the console log states:

```
Retrieve remote issues of project XXXXX... 
Project not found on remote SonarQube server [com.company.xxxx:XXXX] 
Start SonarQube analysis on XXXX... 
INFO: SonarQube Server 4.0
```

I have tried to provision a project for com.company.xxxx:XXXX, and I have turned the security for provisioning off to act like SonarQube 3, but the project analysis does not get added to the server.

So the plugin can clearly contact the server. I have tried to add the admin credentials to the plugin to get past any permission issues. I have overridden the default maven-generated tag name to something else, and also added provisioning for the new name. I keep getting "Project not found" messages.

Am I missing something? The tutorial on the [SonarQube tutorial](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) makes it seem like this is correctly configured, but web searches are not coming up with similar experiences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a result of the Maven integration. Updates are only pushed to the server when running directly against the Maven repository. When running locally the analysis data is compared to the server data to find deltas, but the server data itself is not updated. This actually makes a lot of sense in a team environment, but was a surprise when the SonarQube tutorial calls out Maven integration but not this caveat.

After performing an analysis from the SonarQube server directly against the Maven repo (without Eclipse in the picture at all) the project was created and populated with the data. This data was then available in Eclipse and local analysis would delta against that data (although it would not update it, which also makes sense).